# Mailx command issues in sending copies

Tags: shell-script, aix

`echo "Log files not updated recently" | mailx -s "Negative Alert" -c "abc@gmail.com" -b "xyz@yahoo.com"`

I am receiving this error message.

> The flags you gave make no sense since you are not sending mail

I am running this script from AIX machine.Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `-b`, just drop it.

`echo "Log files not updated recently" | mailx -s "Negative Alert" -c "abc@gmail.com" "xyz@yahoo.com"`

Comment: Thanks, its working. If i need to include multiple recipients in the CC and TO , pls let me know the syntax for it.

Comment: try `man mailx`